# Debian 8 no wlan0 on XPS-13 Intel 8260 (rev 3a)

Tags: debian, firmware, iwlwifi

Freshly installed Debian 8 on a Dell XPS - Developer Edition laptop, and running the 3.16.0-4 kernel since the newer one doesn't boot (dont care to fix that at the moment).

`sudo lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` lists the following:

```
3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0050]
3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
```

I downloaded the firmware (tried both iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode and iwlwifi-8000C-17.ucode) and copied it to `/lib/firmware`, rebooted and nothing changed.

If I try to install using `apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi`, my USB-ethernet adapter stops working as well.

---

**Edit:** Also, my driver (8000-17.ucode) isn't even listed in the `firmware-iwlwifi` packed here:

https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=firmware-iwlwifi

---

errors when trying `make menuconfig`

```
root@001:/linux-4.1.26#
  HOSTCC scripts/kconfig/mconf.o
In file included from scripts/kconfig/mconf.c:23:0:
scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/dialog.h:38:20: fatal error: curses.h: No such file or directory

#include CURSES_LOC
                   ^
compilation terminated.
scripts/Makefile.host:108: recipe for target 'scripts/kconfig/mconf.o' failed
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/mconf.o] Error 1
Makefile:541: recipe for target 'menuconfig' failed
make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
```

Comment: Are you trying to load the `iwlwifi` module: `modprobe iwlwifi` ?

Comment: What firmware is `iwlwifi` looking for on your system? It should tell you the specific file name in the kernel logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Linux* Support for Intel® Wi-Fi Adapters](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) the Intel 8260 is only suppoted by the 4.1 [Kernel](https://kernel.org/) version:

Download and build the 4.1.26 kernel.

Use the `iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0.tgz` driver

Comment: The problem is the `iwlwifi` module is loadable only for a specific kernel version `4.1` .

Comment: downloaded the 4.1.26.tar.xz from kernel.org, but i keep getting errors when I try to run `make menuconfig`

Comment: added errors to the main post

Comment: Run `apt-get install build-essential  libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev`

Comment: Worked perfectly after getting the other 4.5 kernel errors out of the way, thanks!